# Raspberry Pi, GPS (adafruit) and ntp does not work

Tags: gps, ntp

How to achieve that ntpd synchronizes time from GPS?
I have adafruit ultimate gps (without battery). It is connected to raspberry and i got fix. PPS pin not connected. I configured ntpd to use GPS http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_feeding_ntpd_from_gpsd

```
server 127.127.28.0  
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.350 refid GPS
```

also changed ntp init script to run ntpd as root `RUNASUSER=root`. 
if i run  `ntpq -p`, i got:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 SHM(0)          .SHM.            0 l    -    8    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

so, there is no update from GPS and reach is 0.

Here http://blog.petrilopia.net/linux/raspberry-pi-set-time-gps-dongle/ is how to do it without ntp. But then i first must know that gps has fix.

Also in some sites i seen, that some configurations is used address 127.127.**20**.0. But in official documentation is mentioned 127.127.28.0.

Is it possible to get it work without PPS pin?

```
ipcs -m

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x4e545030 0          root       600        80         2
0x4e545031 32769      root       600        80         1
0x4e545032 65538      root       666        80         1
0x4e545033 98307      root       666        80         1
```

ntp version = ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri May 18 20:30:57 UTC 2012 (1)

Comment: Yes, you can get it without PPS - RPi needs some patch to use PPS. Did you check using the gpsd commands that GPS is indeed working? Also checkout http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution (not clean but it works). I added battery to gps, so date and time is saved.
In gps chip [specification](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/GlobalTop-FGPMMOPA6H-Datasheet-V0A.pdf) page 22 `$GPRMC` contains time and date $GPRMC,**191822.247**,A,2907.1856,N,19016.4938,E,0.03,165.48,**031214**,3.05,W,A*2C

And here is /etc/rc.local

```
#start GPSd
gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
# read date & time from GPS
/bin/bash /date_set_from_gps.sh
```

cat /date_set_from_gps.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# $GPRMC,191749.247,V,,,,,0.17,0.00,031214,,,N*4C
r=`gpspipe -R | head -10 | grep GPRMC | head -1 | awk -F"," '{print $10" "$2}'`
# 031214 191822.247
D="20${r:4:2}-${r:2:2}-${r:0:2} ${r:7:2}:${r:9:2}:${r:11:2}"
# I added prefix 20 to year (to get year with 4 digits ex: 2014)

# set date in UTC format.... -u 
DD=`date -us "$D $T"`
```